# What is the difference between a mouseover and a hoverover?

Tags: hover, mouse

I have seen both a 'mouseover' and a 'hoverover' referring to the same thing - but it is not clear if there is a difference.

Is there a functional difference between the two terms, or are they identical in meaning?

Comment: How is this a UX question?

Answer (score 7):

**From documentation**

- mouseover(): [source](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Bind an event handler to the "mouseover" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Meaning only when **the mouse is over** an element.

- .hover(): [source](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer **enters** and **leaves** the elements.

```
Calling $(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)
```

is shorthand for:

`$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

A lot of times, these terms are used together because they describe what should happen when a user places their mouse over an element. How will this element look like? But if you want to talk to a developer, it is nice to know the difference.

This is a good explanation with examples

> The hover() function is more high level - it's built to call functions
>   to handle both a mouseenter event and a mouseleave event. It's very
>   convenient for a UI element that has a hover and normal state (e.g. a
>   button.)
>
> The mouseover() function specifically binds to the mouseover event.
>   It's best for situations where you only care when the mouse has
>   crossed the border into an element and you don't really care what
>   happens if it leaves. It's also the function to call when you want to
>   trigger the event on some element.

From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/jQuery/jQuery-What-is-the-difference-between-the-hover-and-mouseover-functions)

Comment: Good answer. Alas - it is only good for JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

**Is there a functional difference between the two terms, or are they
identical in meaning?**

I think it depends upon who is talking. Most end users will use them interchangeably - which makes sense. As a non-techie a mouseover is basically hovering over the item which causes some "thing" to happen.

However, to someone who write javascript, the two have different meanings.

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

[See: api.jquery.com/hover/](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)